# Convert iterative function to recursive

Tags: c

How can I convert this iterative function into recursive?
The function in question finds any pair in an array given a distance. This is C language by the way

```
int * findPair(int * array, int size, int distance)
{
    int * result = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*3);
    result[0] = 0;
    result[1] = 0;
    result[2] = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < size; j++)
        {
            int diff = array[i] - array[j];

            if (diff == distance) // found a pair
            {
                result[0] = 1;
                result[1] = array[i];
                result[2] = array[j];
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: "finds any pair " --> except that `array[i] - array[j]` may overflow with extreme values.

Comment: @reinstate yes, that's why size is always the size of the array

Comment: the first element in the result array is actually whether a pair has been found or not ! 0 if no, 1 if yes

Comment: Your `break` exits only from one level of loop, but it is in a nested loop.  It does not appear to be useful to continue the outer loop after the `break` is executed, but that's what will happen.

Answer (score 1):

To start with:

It's seldom a good idea to convert an iterative approach to a recursive approach. You should nearly always prefer iterative over recursive. In other words: Only use recursive when it gives you something that is hard to achieve otherwise.

Anyway...

There are many ways to implement what your looking for using recursion.

Below is just one example. **However, I deliberately only removed the inner-loop.** The code should give you ideas about the principle and then - as an exercise - you can remove the remaining loop yourself so that you get a "pure recursive" approach without any for-loops.

```
void findPair_rec(int num, int * array, int size, int distance, int* res)
{
    assert(*res == 0);
    if (size == 0) return;  // Reach the end - no match - just return
    if ((num - *array) == distance)
    {
        // Match found - update result and return
        res[0] = 1;
        res[1] = num;
        res[2] = *array;
        return;
    }
    
    // Recursion - advance array pointer and decrement size
    findPair_rec(num, array + 1, size - 1, distance, res);
}

int * findPair(int * array, int size, int distance)
{
    int * result = calloc(3, sizeof *result);

    for (int i = 0; i < size && result[0] == 0; i++)
    {
        findPair_rec(array[i], array, size, distance, result);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I like recursion.

To approach the problem recursively, reduce it minimally to 0-sized array or 1-sized array ... and then, from that, to (n - 1)-sized array

```
void findPairHelper(int *a, int size, int d, int r[3]) {
    if (size < 2) return;  // base case: no match, r[0] is 0
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
        if (abs(a[i] - a[size - 1]) == d) {
            r[0] = 1;
            r[1] = a[i];
            r[2] = a[size - 1];
            return; ///////////// found
        }
    }
    findPairHelper(a, size - 1, d, r); // recurse with smaller array
}
int *findPair(int *array, int size, int distance) {
    int *result = calloc(3, sizeof *result); // result[0] == 0 means 'no pair found'
    findPairHelper(array, size, distance, result);
    return result; // remember to free(result) at some point
}
```

See https://ideone.com/VuKWtl

Comment: So you undelete again. That's good, I think :-) Even our approaches are somewhat similar there are differences and OP now has two answers to get inspiration from.